# Bot Framework Autofac DI - Passing dependencies when using context.Call()

Tags: c#, autofac, botframework

I've been playing around with the bot framework, but I was just wondering if my usage of Autofac is correct when using using context.Call(). Should I be passing the rating service depency from the RootDialog to the ReviewDialog like this(below), or is there a better way?

```
context.Call(new ReviewDialog(_ratingService), ChildDialogHasCompleted);
```

**MessagesController**

```
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
                {
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => scope.Resolve<IDialog<object>>());
                }
            }

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

**RootDialog**

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    private IRatingService _ratingService;

    public RootDialog(IRatingService ratingService)
    {
        this._ratingService = ratingService;
    }

    [LuisIntent("Movie")]
    public async Task IntentSearch(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        // Do stuff

        context.Call(new ReviewDialog(_ratingService), ChildDialogHasCompleted);
    }

    private async Task ChildDialogHasCompleted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> msg)
    {
        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

**ReviewDialog**

```
[Serializable]
public class ReviewDialog : IDialog
{
    private IRatingService _ratingService;

    public ReviewDialog(IRatingService ratingService)
    {
        this._ratingService = ratingService;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, ProcessRating, new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }, "Please select your rating");
    }

    public async Task ProcessRating(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> msg)
    {
        var message = await msg;

        context.UserData.TryGetValue("SelectedMovieId", out int movieId);

        var rating = int.Parse(message);

        _ratingService.Save(movieId, rating);

        await context.PostAsync("Thank you");

        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

Global

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<RootDialog>()
                .As<IDialog<object>>()
                .InstancePerDependency();

        builder.RegisterType<RatingService>()
                .Keyed<IRatingService>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing this is totally valid.  To see another implementaiton please check out [AlarmBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot)

The way you are doing this is generally how I use DI in dialogs as well.  there is another way to pass data/classes between dialogs using the data bags inside the context `PrivateConversationData`, `ConversationData` and `UserData`, but there is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it